# Drupal Multilanguage domain specific with PORT not working

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have setting up drupal 7 with 2 languages:

1. English Default
2. Spanish

Also, Point 2 domains for each language from language configuration settings

- www.drupal-experiment.local:90 (English)
- es.drupal-experiment.local:90 (Spanish)

**Setting.php**
Base URL set in /sites/default/settings.php file.

> $base_url = "http://www.drupal-experiment.local:90";

Can anyone look at my configuration, where I have missed something so, Other/inner links are not getting PORT with given URL.

e.g. If I try to login it will submit data to URL without PORT number.

> http://www.drupal-experiment.local/

See attached screen-shots for configuration set for domain with PORT 90.

> **Languages list**

[image]

> **English Language Configuration**

[image]

> **Spanish Language Configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confident that the reason for your issue / problem, is because [Language detection by domain only works on port 80](https://www.drupal.org/node/1572394). That issue has 'some patches' attached to it', and status = Needs review.

Not sure if you want to try/consider experimenting with any of the patches in this issue though.

Something else you may want to check is your configuration at `Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection`: the order specified there could be what explains the current behaviour in your site.

You'd have to experiment a bit with what the exact order in your case should be. In my experience, I often get these kind of issues to work by using an order like 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'. So try to experiment a bit with the various combinations in this order to see if it helps.

Curious to hear if either of those options will somehow help ...

Comment: I have used one patch and modify my locale.inc in which I have tried to added PORT Number behind the url and after cleaning all cache of site it will working fine all URL.

It is better solution to modify in locale.inc file or it is for temporary solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment. What is the patch you are referring to (any link where to find it)?